# How do I call findViewWithTag in the OnCreate() method of an activity?

Tags: android

I get an error when I call `findViewWithTag()` in the `onCreate()`

> "The method `findViewWithTag(String)` is undefined for the type
>   MainActivity"

Is there any alternative?

Comment: It's findViewWithTag only, right?

Comment: The method is [`View#findViewWithTag()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewWithTag%28java.lang.Object%29), it is not part of the Activity class. Perhaps you want to use the more useful `findViewById()` method?

Comment: @Sam no, I really need to use findViewWithTag because I have to loop through a number of TextViews and set their text. Hence I have added tags to each of them, starting from 01, 02 ... till say, 26, 27.
It's easier for me to access the tag as it is a string.
Is there some way out which uses only their id?

Comment: The TextViews must be held in some type of ViewGroup (like LinearLayout). You need to get a reference to this ViewGroup, the easiest is to give it an id and use `LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.xxx)`. Now you can call `layout.findViewWithTag(tag)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`findViewWithTag()` is only defined for a View.

If you have a reference to the contentView of the activity that you set with `setContentView(contentView)`, you can use `contentView.findViewWithTag()`.

If you don't have a reference to that view, you can also use `findViewById(R.id.your_content_view_id).findViewWithTag(tag)`.

Comment: Half-correct, the method really is [`findViewWithTag()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewWithTag%28java.lang.Object%29), but it is part of View not the Activity class.

Comment: @Sam, Yeah, that is what I've mentioned. Is there any mistake with my answer?

Comment: @Sam, Thanks for catching that! Too much of auto suggestion, I think!