# How to use addRule() with a tag dynamically inside a loop it takes Exception when inflating View?

Tags: android, view, android-relativelayout

I have a loop to add a variable number of views to a RelativeLayout, and I want to set some Rules like `BELOW`, my problem is that I'm using tags to name the objects dynamically, and to use the `addRule()` method I need to use an id, so what I tried is to set an Id every time that the loop is runned and it's not the first time.

This is my code:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= kNumberofViews; i++){
    View = new MyView(context);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(kViewWidth, kViewHeight);
    params.setMargins(kMarginLeft, kMarginTop, kMarginRight, kMarginBottom);
    params.addRule(CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    if (i != 1){
        MyView view = (MyView)view.findViewWithTag(i-1);
        view.setId(i);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, view.getId());
    }
    View.setTag(i);
    View.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    System.out.println("View " + i +" added correctly");
    addView(View, params);
}
```

How can I solve it?

EDIT:

```
05-18 14:57:19.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5500): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-18 14:57:19.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5500): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{me.gabrielesteban.app/me.gabrielesteban.app.MyRelativeLayoutTest}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class me.gabrielesteban.app.GD.MyRelativeLayout
05-18 14:57:19.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5500):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
05-18 14:57:19.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5500):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2357)
05-18 14:57:19.549: E/AndroidRuntime(5500):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
```

EDIT 2:

I think that the problem is in the following line `MyView view = (MyView)view.findViewWithTag(i-1);`, is this line correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reviewed My code again and also I read [How do I call findViewWithTag in the OnCreate() method of an activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545253/how-do-i-call-findviewwithtag-in-the-oncreate-method-of-an-activity) and I see that when I call the findViewWithTag() method put the same object that I'm finding before the method, so the result was that don't find an object inside that object with that tag, so the only thing that I have to do was delete that part.

```
MyView view = (MyView)view.findViewWithTag(i-1); //Bad way to find the View

MyView view = (MyView)findViewWithTag(i-1); //Good way to find the View by tag
```

Answer (score 1):

Try checking if there is an ID assigned before assigning a new one!

```
for(int i = 1; i <= kNumberofViews; i++){
    View v = new MyView(context);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(kViewWidth, kViewHeight);
    params.setMargins(kMarginLeft, kMarginTop, kMarginRight, kMarginBottom);
    params.addRule(CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    if (i != 1){
        MyView view = (MyView)findViewWithTag(i-1);
        if (view.getId() == View.NO_ID)
            view.setId(i);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, view.getId());
    }
    View.setTag(i);
    View.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    System.out.println("View " + i +" added correctly");
    addView(View, params);
}
```

**EDIT**

Edited, checked the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getId%28%29) and you are right, a view can't be null, but if there is no view assigned the returned value is [View.NO_ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#NO_ID) (Or -1).

Comment: it takes me an Exception when inflating the view that contains this loop, I will post the logCat output